# Select MAX value and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to extract ID values where End_Time for type A is not equal to Max End_Time of each System_Id

```
ID     System_Id Type  End_Time
1        1         A    10:00
1        1         B    12:00
1        2         A    14:00
1        2         B    14:00
2        3         A    07:00
2        3         B    07:00
```

So end result should be:

```
ID    System_ID   Type  End_Time
1        1          A     10:00
```

For now I was trying this:

```
Select ID 
From TestTable t 
WHERE t.Type LIKE 'A'
AND t.End_Time < 
(
    SELECT MAX(t2.End_Time)
    From TestTable t2
    Order by System_Id
)
```

I think this query should be somewhat ok, because if I ask in the subquery for a specific ID, and outside it - it returns a proper answer.
I think that I need to somehow group it also by ID, however I don't really know how. Database is Oracle if that changes some things.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TestTable t1
WHERE t1.Type = 'A'
  AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM TestTable t2
        WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.End_Time > t1.End_Time 
      );
```

or a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM TestTable t1 INNER JOIN TestTable t2
ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.End_Time > t1.End_Time
WHERE t1.Type = 'A';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=04d844c618851f31be9c9d2706d1e684).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ID, System_Id, Type, End_Time
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY system_id ORDER BY end_time DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   testtable t
)
WHERE  type = 'A'
AND    rnk > 1;
```

Or, the `MAX` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ID, System_Id, Type, End_Time
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX(end_time) OVER (PARTITION BY system_id) AS max_end_time
  FROM   testtable t
)
WHERE  type = 'A'
AND    end_time < max_end_time;
```

Or, can fix your query by correlating the sub-query to the outer query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TestTable t 
WHERE  t.Type = 'A'
AND    t.End_Time < ( SELECT MAX(t2.End_Time)
                      FROM   TestTable t2
                      WHERE  t.system_id = t2.system_id )
```

*Note: The first two queries only `SELECT ... FROM TestTable` once and the outer query is purely for filtering the existing data. The final query `SELECT ... FROM TestTable` twice and will likely be less efficient.*

---

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testtable (ID, System_Id, Type, End_Time) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'A', INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'B', INTERVAL '12:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'A', INTERVAL '14:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'B', INTERVAL '14:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 'A', INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 'B', INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

All queries output:

> | ID | SYSTEM_ID | TYPE | END_TIME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | A | +00 10:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=57a850bde691d80214e7a9c43e54dee1)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, GROUP BY should be used for this query. Please try:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID
FROM   Testtable T1
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT ID, MAX(END_TIME) AS END_TIME_MAX
         FROM Testtable
         GROUP BY ID
       ) T2
       ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE  T1.END_TIME < T2.END_TIME_MAX
AND    T1.Type = 'A'
```